# Successful Query Result but Unable to Display Results

Tags: database

I'm expecting one row query result in my query commands below:

```
//Retrieve ID Preview Information fom the database  
$query = db_select('student', 't1',array('target' => 'import'));
$query->join('studinfo', 't2', 't1.studid = t2.studid');
$query->join('semstudent', 't3', 't1.studid = t3.studid');
$query->join('program', 't4', 't4.progcode = t3.studmajor');

$result = $query
   ->fields('t1', array('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'extname'))
   ->fields('t2', array('guardian', 'mobile', 'homephone'))   
   ->fields('t4', array('progcode', 'college'))    
   ->condition('t1.studid','0006-10014','=')
   ->distinct()
   ->execute();  

if($result){
    watchdog('print','successful');
    foreach($result as $row ){
        watchdog('print', 'inside the loop');
    }
}else
{
    watchdog('print','not successful');
}
```

In my `watchdog` table in my database, `'successful'` is the only log I saw. That means it doesn't get inside my loop which I know for sure that I have one row result. Where am I missing?

Comment: If the `foreach` isn't entered it's more than likely the query doesn't have any results. Check `count($result->fetchAll())` to make sure

Comment: @Clive --> I'm pretty much sure that I must have one row of result. I confirmed it through looking in my database.

Comment: The results suggest otherwise. Check what you've actually got in php, not in the db

Comment: `var_dump($result);` or install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and `dpm($result)`

Comment: After the ->execute(); use a ->fetch of your choice. [Dynamic Query result sets](https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174)